# How to create Own Artifactory on Cloud like Code Artifact from AWS, Artifactoy from Jfrog

Tags: node.js, maven, artifactory, mvn-repo

I want to create my own artifactory for Maven, Ndoe Projects that I work currently I have use
Code Artifacts from AWS and Jfrog from Artifactory.

But they resulted in very expensive as my usages started increasing.  Is there any way I can create my own artifactory from my private usages on Cloud.

I may need to store

1. Docker Images
2. Maven Jar Files
3. Node Artifacts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to setup a self hosted instance of artifactory there are a few free flavors here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Self-Hosted .

JFrog Container Registry - free docker registry.

Artifactory OSS - Maven repositories.

No free self hosted npm registry from JFrog.

The cloud free tier includes all supported package types but has limit on the usage. See https://jfrog.com/pricing/ for more details.

Comment: Yes I want self hosted . But not using jfrog. Actually it's very expensive. I tried Archiva by Apache but its build is Java 8 supported .and feature are also very less